# Unable to see the code and design in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I accidentally deleted my project from **visual studio2013/projects/myproject**.  I did a system restore and got the folder myproject.  I am unable to see my code form or design form but I can run my application.

What d I have to do to be able to edit my code?

Comment: This is the reason why one needs to make backups. Seriously did you get back the SLN file? Are you able to double click on it and open your project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

System Restore will only revert the computer's state (including system files, installed applications, Windows Registry, and system settings), not user files, and your sourcecode files are user files.

Since you can still run the application, then you must have a compiled executable somewhere. I suggest that you download `dotPeek` from JetBrains and then you can open your application up in it and decompile your assembly back into source code.

The code will be a bit ugly; your nice, meaningful variable names will probably be gone, but at least it's a starting point. Here's the link to dotPeek. https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

BTW, I'm assuming that you've already tried to get the files back from the Recycle Bin.